# My system setting wiped out after I uninstalled my lampp

Tags: 14.04

I'm new in Ubuntu 14.04, after I uninstalled my lampp to change it for a new one, my system setting wiped out. Is there a way to return it back? without re-installing my desktop OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run:
$ unity-control-center.

If doesn't appear try to install:
$ sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

Comment: Could you please hit as an answer to help some others.